# IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed (on first getContent())

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-get

```
private HttpResponse doResponse(String url) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());
    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }

    return response;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
    String url = urls[0];
    String result ="";

    try {
        HttpResponse response=doResponse(url);
        result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
        //throws IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    } 

    return result;
}
```

the line

```
result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

throws

```
IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed
```

even though I didn't get the content before.

I would like to know witch part of my code is consuming the content before

```
response.getEntity().getContent();
```

I'm on Samsung galaxy tab 2
Running Android 4.1.1

Comment: Please show us the code for `inputStreamToString()`

Comment: @Asok thx for your help help (I can't explain why) but the exception is here just with debug mode , nothing is wrong on run mode ,

may be its the timeout of the http request

Comment: Make sure that you are only calling `getContent()` once, make sure you are not calling it inside your method `inputStreamToString()`.

Comment: I have this error with Xamarin.Android only while debugging too. I suppose, that debugger read content before us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are only calling `getContent()` once. Verify that in your `inputStreamToString()` method you're not calling it. `getContent()` returns an input stream and you can only return an input stream once per connection.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent%28%29):

> **getContent()**
>
> Creates a new InputStream object of the entity. ***It is a programming error to return the same InputStream object more than once***. Entities that are not repeatable will throw an exception if this method is called multiple times.